# put a message onto a queue from JAVA

Tags: java, mq

Hi guys I am new to java and when I tried to import com.ibm.mq in eclipse, and it is complaining com.ibm.mq cannot be resolved. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You're missing the library.

Comment: trying to download com.ibm.mq.jar.

Comment: found com.ibm.mq.jar in websphere mq folder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `com.ibm.mq.jar` is on your classpath. Since you are using Eclipse you can simply add this jar file to the classpath by opening your Projects's properties page. Then select 'Java Build Path'. Next, on the 'Libraries' tab add the jar file

If you are using `java` or `javac` use the -classpath flag

`java -classpath c:\path\to\com.ibm.mq.jar` ...

`javac -classpath c:\path\to\com.ibm.mq.jar` ...

Answer (score 1):

Grab the [Maven dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.ibm%7Ccom.ibm.mq%7C5.3.07%7Cjar)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.07</version>
</dependency>
```